# How can I create a metafield with the type: product, for a shopify input?

Tags: shopify

I have made several metafields with the type as product, so I know they work, but in this section they don't show up for this link.  I can hardcode the link to a specific product, but I want it to be dynamic using metafields. I'm using the [palo alto](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/palo-alto/styles/palo-alto) theme.

[image]

and this is the result when I click the `dynamic source` button:

[image]

I'd rather leave any theme customization or coding as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

A link would take a metafield of type `url` but you are trying to add a metafield of type `product`. Type product stores the product object with all its data that's not what you need here if you just need to link to the product page.

Id just set up another metafield of type url and pop the url of the product in there.

I'm not familiar with where you are adding this in the Palo Alto theme but unless this is a section that appears on multiple pages, like product pages or blog pages, where you need to link to a different product on each page you may not need a metafield at all.

Comment: where do i obtain the `url of the product`?

Comment: nvm i found it.  this works but it feels very brittle.  (eg. domain name changes will be bad).  anyways it works, thanks!